# Adding Tab bar in part of uiviewcontroller, monotouch iphone

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, uitabbar

I want to add a tabbar to a uiviewcontroller like this image:

[image]

The top part (2labels and UIScrollView ) are fix and just the bottom part change when user changed tab bar items.
I added the tab bar controller from object in xcode to my uiviewcontroller but i have no idea how we can create views of tab bar controller how just change part of page.

EDIT:
I use this code for this:

```
        UIViewController viewController1, viewController2;
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone) {
            viewController1 = new FirstViewController ("FirstViewController_iPhone", null);
            viewController2 = new SecondViewController ("SecondViewController_iPhone", null);
        } else {
            viewController1 = new FirstViewController ("FirstViewController_iPad", null);
            viewController2 = new SecondViewController ("SecondViewController_iPad", null);
        }
        UITabBarController tabBarController= new UITabBarController ();
        tabBarController.ViewControllers = new UIViewController [] {
            viewController1,
            viewController2,
        };

        UIView v= tabBarController .View ;
        v.Frame = new Rectangle (0,150,320,260);
        UITabBar tb= tabBarController .TabBar;
        tb.Frame = new RectangleF (0,410,320,50);
        this.View .AddSubview (v  );
        this .View .AddSubview (tb);
```

but it is not working. The tab bar view fill all the view and when i click on buttons of uitabbar i get exception and app force close.

Answer (score 1):

You might not need the tabbar to reproduce this behavior.

1. In your "place should change...", just set a plain UIView and we are going to call it container.
2. In your view controller's viewDidLoad, create your three views and keep them in memory let's call them detailView, mapView, agentView.

Then, at the bottom, you can just add 3 UIButton. On each button press action (TouchUpInside) you add the related view as container subview (i.e agentButton.TouchUpInside += () => container.AddSubView(detailsView); * do not forget to remove the previous one.

EDIT :

```
this.View .AddSubview (tabBarController.View);
tabBarController.View.Frame = new RectangleF(....);
```

I've tried this in a sample project and it works

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes it is possible. but by this way we should care to change state of icons when they pressed and when they unpress. Also create some custom view when number of buttons be more that 4. almost we have to implement all features that before had implemented in tabbar again for our container. I think it is better that we find a way to use tabbar controller for this also.

Comment: Using tabbar controller would be a little more complicated. but the main idea would be to add a TabBarController as a child controller of your UIViewController. and then set it's view frame to make it fit your white rectangle. (and add tabbarController.view as a subview of the other UIViewController)

Comment: Thanks Marc. I believe that we have to do this so. Do you have any source codes or tutorials for this. Really i'm a new on monotouch iphone and this materials help me so :)

Comment: I'm not sure you need to add the TabBar itself. Shouldn't it be contained within the tabbarController.View ?

Comment: What we can do about tabbarController.View? While i changed its frame size but ye it fill all the page :-S